# Which version of Dreamweaver supports HTML 5?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

We know that Macromedia Dreamweaver 8 supports HTML 4.Is there any  HTML 5 plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dreamweaver cs5.5
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/whats-new-dwcs55.html

Comment: i think this answers my question.. so.. DWCS5 doesn't support it?? because i'm about to freak out! the layout looks absolutely broken on DWCS5!!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the [announcement](http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/pressroom/pressreleases/201005/051910HTML5Pack.html) to which you refer.

> The Adobe HTML5 Pack is an extension to Adobe Dreamweaver CS5, the latest version of the industry-leading HTML authoring tool for website design. This extension provides more creative options to Adobe Creative Suite 5 users – so they can more easily create, deliver and optimize compelling content consistently, across the widest array of screens, to maximize revenue streams and forward their businesses.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver CS5 does not support HTML5 'out of the box'. 
I do remember seeing something online about a package in which could be downloaded from abobe.com which would enable HTML5 support for CS5, but I am not 100% about this..
By the way... Dreamwaver CS6 which is available, also supports HTML5.